# What kind of weapons can Momo create?

Tags: my-hero-academia

Can momo create any kind of weapon? I've seen she creates a shield and a staff and I believe she once created a sort of bazooka. Could she create a very powerful weapon to destroy anything? Or do her power have any limits in which weapons she can create?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, **she can create any kind of weapon** as long as she has an understanding of how something is made.

If you take a look at the [wiki](http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/Momo_Yaoyorozu):

> Momo's Quirk gives her the ability to create any non-living material from her uncovered body through the molecular manipulation of her fat cells. As long as she has an understanding of how something is made, she can create it. However, it takes her a longer period of time (and more of her skin being exposed) to create large objects.

But yes, she has limits:

> She states that the more she eats, the more material she has to work with, so she needs considerable ingestion of food for her Quirk to be effective. This makes a possible danger that she would likely become extremely underweight if her Quirk is used too much.